# Trying to model a substance settling in water using an advection equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, finite-differences

I am trying to model a substance dispersed in a container of water gradually settling at the bottom. I am considering only one dimension. The top is at $z = 1$, and the bottom is at $z = 0$.

So at $t = 0$ the concentration $u = 0.2$ everyhwere.

As time goes on the substance moves to the bottom where it settles and eventually the concentration should be

$
  u(z, t)=\begin{cases}
               0 & \text{if} \ z > 0.2\\
               1 & \text{if} \ z <= 0.2\\
            \end{cases}
$

I thought an advection type equation might work so I used

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = - v(u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$$

with initial condition

$
  u(z, 0)=\begin{cases}
               0 & \text{if} \ z = 1\\
               0.2 & \text{if} \ 0 < z < 1\\
               1 & \text{if} \ z = 0 \\
            \end{cases}
$

But while the concentration in the upper part of the container does go to $0$, the concentration in the bottom stays at $0.2$ instead of going to $1$.
[image][image]

I used the method of lines with finite differences. I've attached the code below so that hopefully someone can see where I've gone wrong and tell me how to fix it so that the concentration ends being $1$ between $z = 0$ and $z = 0.2$?

```
function mol_edbl
clear
clc

global n

% Time and spatial steps
n = 51;

% Time start and finish
t0 = 0.0;
tf = 1;
t_grid_points = linspace(t0,tf,n);

% Spatial start and finish
z0 = 0;
zf = 1;
z_grid_points = linspace(z0,zf,n);

dz = (zf-z0)/(n-1);

% Initial condition
for i=1:n
    u_l0(i) = 0.2;
    v_l0(i) = 0;
end

u_l0(1) = 1;

u_l0(n) = 0;


ics = [ u_l0 v_l0 ];

reltol=1.0e-04; abstol=1.0e-04;
options=odeset('RelTol',reltol,'AbsTol',abstol);
[t, solved]=ode15s(@solve, t_grid_points, ics, options);

u_l_solved = solved(1:n,1:n);
v_l_solved = solved(1:n,n+1:2*n);

% Store numerical and analytical solutions, errors at z = 1/2
  n2=(n-1)/2.0+1;
  sine=sin(pi/2.0*0.5);
  for i=1:n
    u_l_plot(i) = u_l_solved(i,n);
    v_l_plot(i) = v_l_solved(i,n);
  end
%

% --------------------%
% Plot
% --------------------%
% **************************************** %
% Display Results - Solution in 3d - Style 2
% **************************************** %
figure(1);
set(gcf,'Position',[200 100 1400 700]);
subplot(1,2,1)

mesh(t_grid_points, z_grid_points, u_l_solved');
title('u_l');
xlabel('t, time')
ylabel('z, distance')
zlabel('u_l(z,t)')

subplot(1,2,2)
mesh(t_grid_points, z_grid_points, v_l_solved');
title('v_l');
xlabel('t, time')
ylabel('z, distance')
zlabel('v_l(z,t)')
rotate3d on;

% --------------------%
% Solver
% --------------------%
function dt = solve(t, u)

u_l = u(1:n);
v_l   = u(n+1:2*n);

for i=1:n
    dv_l(i) = 0;

    if i == 1
        du_l(i) = 0;
    elseif i == n
        du_l(i) = 0;
    else
        du_l_dz = (u_l(i+1) - u_l(i))/dz;
        v = - 1 + 2 * u_l(i);
        du_l(i) =  - v * du_l_dz;
    end
end

dt = [ du_l' ; dv_l' ];
end

end

u_l0(1) = 1;

u_l0(n) = 0;


ics = [ u_l0 v_l0 ];

reltol=1.0e-04; abstol=1.0e-04;
options=odeset('RelTol',reltol,'AbsTol',abstol);
[t, solved]=ode15s(@solve, t_grid_points, ics, options);

u_l_solved = solved(1:n,1:n);
v_l_solved = solved(1:n,n+1:2*n);

% Store numerical and analytical solutions, errors at z = 1/2
  n2=(n-1)/2.0+1;
  sine=sin(pi/2.0*0.5);
  for i=1:n
    u_l_plot(i) = u_l_solved(i,n);
    v_l_plot(i) = v_l_solved(i,n);
  end
%

% --------------------%
% Plot
% --------------------%
% **************************************** %
% Display Results - Solution in 3d - Style 2
% **************************************** %
figure(1);
set(gcf,'Position',[200 100 1400 700]);
subplot(1,2,1)

mesh(t_grid_points, z_grid_points, u_l_solved');
title('u_l');
xlabel('t, time')
ylabel('z, distance')
zlabel('u_l(z,t)')

subplot(1,2,2)
mesh(t_grid_points, z_grid_points, v_l_solved');
title('v_l');
xlabel('t, time')
ylabel('z, distance')
zlabel('v_l(z,t)')
rotate3d on;

% --------------------%
% Solver
% --------------------%
function dt = solve(t, u)

    u_l = u(1:n);
    v_l   = u(n+1:2*n);

    for i=1:n
        dv_l(i) = 0;

        if i == 1
            du_l(i) = 0;
        elseif i == n
            du_l(i) = 0;
        else
            du_l_dz = (u_l(i+1) - u_l(i))/dz;
            v = - 1 + 2 * u_l(i);
            du_l(i) =  - v * du_l_dz;
        end
    end

    dt = [ du_l' ; dv_l' ];
end

end
```

Comment: Mathematically, how did you define your velocity? In particular, why is your velocity such that the material stabilizes in a "stack" of height 0.2, rather than compressing into the bottom? Also, in the weak sense your initial condition is actually just $0.2$. This weak sense is really what gets reflected in any numerical calculation, except where you force it to be otherwise. This may explain some of your problems; for instance it probably explains the fact that you have a jump at $z=0$ for all time.

Comment: I'm also not sure about good boundary conditions for this problem. Physically, the material is moving down (but for the moment let's not presuppose the evolution equation for this motion), and none of it is leaving the container. This would mean that you would want a no-flux condition at the top and bottom. But with advection, you can't impose any boundary condition at all at the bottom, as I explained in your other question. You might work around this by introducing a diffusion effect. (In a random walk model, this corresponds to a particle which usually goes down but occasionally goes up.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to define the velocity to get it to model the substance settling. I coded the above based on what I found on page 306 here - https://books.google.ie/books?id=A_1LbCbIgEkC&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=differential+equation+settling+at+bottom&source=bl&ots=XvyCIX1oH0&sig=Hjd8h8jFZxT8vDucaKphfx2R0jE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMIscO13PG8xwIVEEfbCh0How0Y#v=onepage&q=differential%20equation%20settling%20at%20bottom&f=false

Comment: I was wondering the same as you...how is the concentration supposed to rise near the bottom when the characteristics are just helping us with the flow at the top of the container.

Comment: If you have any idea for the proper form other equation/or code to model this I would appreciate as I've been trying to figure out how to do this for two days now! :'-(

Comment: How crucial is it that the equilibrium is what you specified? If it isn't that big a deal, then you could do something like this: $u_t=\varepsilon u_{xx}-ku_x$, and then work out what $\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^1 u(x,t) dx$ is and set it equal to zero (this is basically your "boundary condition", which under sufficient regularity is actually a boundary condition). Then $\varepsilon,k$ are basically tuning parameters. Maybe you can send $\varepsilon \to 0$.